# Как самостоятельно определить день недели по дате используя только базовые операции?

Tags: delphi, дата

> Даны: число, месяц и год. На какой день недели приходится эта дата?
>
> Использовать следующие объявления типов и переменных:
>
> ```
> Type
>   TDays = 1..31;
>   TMonths = (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec);
>   TDayOfWeek = (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat);
>
> Var
>   day: TDays;
>   month: TMonths;
>   dayOfWeek: TDayOfWeek;
>   monthInput: 1..12;
> ```
>
> Работать с функциями `Succ`, `Pred` и `Ord`.

Странное очень задание и я не понимаю как его можно выполнить. Есть ли у кого какие предложения?

Идеальный вариант так, ну думаю это не прокатит

```
ShowMessageFmt(
  'День недели на %s : %s', 
  [
    DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date),
    FormatSettings.LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(DateTimePicker1.Date)]
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для определения дня недели по дате есть несколько [готовых алгоритмов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week).

Вот, для примера, реализация алгоритма Джона Конвея "Судный День" (John Conway, Doomsday) из библиотеки Indy:

```
function Indy_DayOfWeek(const AYear, AMonthOfYear, ADayOfMonth: Integer): Integer;
var
  a, y, m, d, mnth : Integer;
begin
  mnth := AMonthOfYear;
  a := (14 - mnth) div 12;
  y := AYear - a;
  m := mnth + (12 * a) - 2;
  d := ADayOfMonth + y + (y div 4) - (y div 100) + (y div 400) + ((31 * m) div 12);
  Result := d mod 7;
end;
```

Объяснение алгоритма можно найти в интернете (если вам придётся его объяснять преподавателю). Рекомендую статью: [Algorithm to calculate the day of the week](http://www.academia.edu/31413474/Algorithm_to_calculate_the_day_of_the_week).

Общий вид алгоритма (на последней странице указанной статьи):

```
y - year  
m - month (1 January to 12 December)  
d - day (1 to 31) 
w - week day (0 Sunday to 6 Saturday)  

t(m) = (5, 1, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2) 
if m <= 2 then y = y - 1 
S = y / 100 - y / 400 – 2 
w = (y + y / 4 – S + t + d) mod 7
```

Пример расчёта дня недели для 5 Марта 2016 года:

```
 d = 5
 m = 3
 y = 2016
 t = 0
 S = 2016/100 - 2016/400 – 2 = 20 - 5 – 2 = 13
 w = (2016 + 504 – 13 + 0 + 5) mod 7 = 6 (Суббота)
```